# If $\mathrm{M,N}$ are $3\times 2, 2 \times 3$ matrices such that $\mathrm{MN}=$ is given. Then $\mathrm{det(NM)}$ is?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $\mathrm{M,N}$ are $3\times 2, 2 \times 3$ matrices such that $\mathrm{MN}=\pmatrix{8& 2 & -2\\2& 5& 4\\-2& 4&5}$, then $\mathrm{det(NM)}$ is?
>
> ($\mathrm{NM}$ is invertible.)

$\mathrm{det(MN)}$ must be (and is) zero. But how to find $\mathrm{det(NM)}$? Any hint?

Comment: Interesting. We could potentially cook up different sets of $M,N$ that yield the same product $MN$, why would $\det N_1M_1 = \det N_2M_2$ even have to hold?

Comment: You mean, without giving $N,M$?

Comment: @AlvinLepik In general it does not: Since $MN$ is a $3 \times 3$ product of matrices of rank $\leq 2$, we have $\operatorname{rank}(MN) \leq 2$, and so $\det(MN) = 0$. But one can choose $M, N$ such that $\det(NM) \neq 0$. For example, take $M$ and $N$ to be matrices given by padding the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix with zero entries on the bottom and right, resp.

Comment: Just as an aside: The question is problem B6 on the 1969 Putnam Exam.

Comment: here is an answer found among Putnam archives. https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol6912.html   The question was also different. The point is that the minimal polynomial is $x^2 - 9x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** If $p \geq q$ and $M, N$ are $p \times q$ and $q \times p$ matrices, respectively, then the characteristic polynomials of $p, q$ are related by
$$
p_{MN}(\lambda) = \lambda^{p - q} p_{NM}(\lambda) .
$$

Comment: Isn't there a minus missing?

Comment: here is an answer, evidently the original question was rather different..  https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol6912.html   where they were told to show the reverse product gave $9I$

Comment: Travis, is there a name I might be able to look up for the theorem you are quoting? New one on me.

Comment: @Sudix That depends on whether your convention for $p_A(\lambda)$ is $\det (\lambda I - A)$ or its negative; I prefer the former convention, so that $p_A$ is monic even when the size $n$ of $A$ is odd (this comes at the cost of the constant term being $(-1)^n \det A$ rather than just $\det A$). If you use the latter convention, then like you say, $\lambda^{q - p}$ in the identity should be replaced with $(-\lambda)^{q - p}$.

Comment: @WillJagy I don't know whether the theorem has a name, but it appears in Horn & Johnson's classic *Matrix Analysis* as Theorem 1.3.22. There's a short proof: Computing confirms that
$$\pmatrix{0_q&\cdot\\M&MN} = \pmatrix{I_q&-N\\\cdot&I_p} \pmatrix{NM&\cdot\\M&0_p} \pmatrix{I_q&N\\\cdot&I_p} ;$$ since the first and last matrices on the r.h.s. are inverses, the second matrix on the r.h.s. and the matrix on the l.h.s. are similar and so have the same characteristic polynomial. By block triangularity, that polynomial is $$\lambda^p p_{NM}(\lambda) = \lambda^q p_{MN}(\lambda) .$$

Comment: NB one can sharpen this result slightly: In fact the Jordan decompositions of $MN$ and $NM$ have the same sizes and counts of Jordan blocks for every nonzero eigenvalue.

Comment: @TravisWillse are the dots supposed to be zero matrices? Or else I don't see how the matrices are block triangular..

Comment: @lcv Yes, in each use `\cdot` denotes a zero matrix (of the only possible size).

Comment: Thanks. I see you took the pain of writing $0_p$ but indeed $0_{p,q}$ would have been almost too much.

Comment: Travis, thank you. I have H+J, in my (paperback) edition it is 1.3.20 on page 53. That's really nice.  There is a proof from pages 53-54, then an alternate as question 9 on page 55

Comment: @WillJagy You're welcome. The theorem number I mentioned is that in the second edition (2013, apparently), where the result appears on p. 65. By the way, the Jordan block statement does not always hold for the zero eigenvalue, and hence the analogous statement for minimal polynomials is false, i.e., one can pick $M, N$ (both square, even) such that $m_{MN} \neq m_{NM}$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to proceed, not knowing the relevant theorem( new one for me as well) is to guess that, being symmetric, this is a Gram matrix. Look for integer rectangles...

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 2 \\
2 & -1 \\
1 & -2 
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & -1 & -2
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
8 & 2 & -2 \\
2 & 5 & 4 \\
-2 & 4 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & -1 & -2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 2 \\
2 & -1 \\
1 & -2 
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
9 & 0 \\
0 & 9
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Indeed, the first characteristic polynomial is $x^3 - 18 x^2 + 81x$ and the second is $x^2 - 18 x + 81$

Comment: Nice but this doesn't show that the answer is independent from the concrete 'parametrization'.

Comment: @lcv sure. I would like to encourage the students to experiment a bit when they have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Agree. Always a good philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can calculate the value of $NM$ explicitly by solving for the right variables.

The order isn't all that sophisticated though.